# How to conditionally rearrange row order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has 'unknown' in each group. I am thinking to put 'unknown' at the end of each group.
For example:
I have a code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
clients1 = {'Name': ['A','B','Unknown','Y','Z','A','B','Unknown','Y','Z'],
        'group': ['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(clients1, columns= ['Name', 'group'])
df
```

the output:

```
   Name group
    A   1
    B   1
    Unknown 1
    Y   1
    Z   1
    A   2
    B   2
    Unknown 2
    Y   2
    Z   2
```

the desired output should be:

```
   Name group
    A   1
    B   1
    Y   1
    Z   1
    Unknown 1
    A   2
    B   2
    Y   2
    Z   2
    Unknown 2
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data by `group` and `name==Unknown`, so the `Unknown`'s are marked with `True` and put at the bottom:

```
df = (df.assign(unknown_name=df['Name'].eq('Unknown'))
        .sort_values(['group','unknown_name'])
     )
```

Output:

```
      Name group  unknown_name
0        A     1         False
1        B     1         False
3        Y     1         False
4        Z     1         False
2  Unknown     1          True
5        A     2         False
6        B     2         False
8        Y     2         False
9        Z     2         False
7  Unknown     2          True
```

Comment: I've done that in SQL many times, when I didn't have the ability to create dtypes.  Great answer.  +1

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!  use df = df.drop('unknown_name', 1) to drop the unknown_name column!

Answer (score 1):

one way you might want to consider is to replace 'unknown' with 'NaN':

```
df["Name"].replace('Unknown', np.NaN,inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by=['group','Name'], inplace=True)

>>> output 
Name group
0    A     1
1    B     1
3    Y     1
4    Z     1
2  NaN     1
5    A     2
6    B     2
8    Y     2
9    Z     2
7  NaN     2
```

and ofcource you can replace back the NaNs with unknown again

Answer (score 0):

Mind the right order of your items:

```
import pandas as pd
clients1 = {'Name': ['A','B','Y','Z', 'Unknown','A','B','Y','Z', 'Unknown'],
        'group': ['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(clients1, columns= ['Name', 'group'])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use category dtype like this:

```
l = df['Name'].unique().tolist()
u = l.pop(l.index('Unknown'))
l.append(u)

n_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(l, ordered=True)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(n_dtype)

df.sort_values(['group', 'Name'])
```

Output:

```
      Name group
0        A     1
1        B     1
3        Y     1
4        Z     1
2  Unknown     1
5        A     2
6        B     2
8        Y     2
9        Z     2
7  Unknown     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any sorting and extra column. It will preserve the original order of the `group` field and so should be more generic. The logic is similar to manipulating the string. For each group, something like `group[:Unknown] + group[Unknown+1:] + Unknown`

```
def func(x):
  result=pd.DataFrame()
  idx = np.flatnonzero(x['Name']=='Unknown')  # get "boolean indices" for using iloc
  prev = None
  for i in idx:
    result = result.append(x.iloc[prev:i,:])
    prev = i+1
  result = result.append(x.iloc[prev:,:])  # last block after Unknown
  for i in idx:
    result = result.append(x.iloc[i, :])  # for appending Unknown records
  return result

df.groupby('group').apply(func).droplevel(0)
   Name group
0   A   1
1   B   1
3   Y   1
4   Z   1
2   Unknown 1
5   A   2
6   B   2
8   Y   2
9   Z   2
7   Unknown 2
```